# Babel/React - convert scss/sass imports to css imports

Tags: reactjs, sass, babeljs

I have React project, which I working with .scss style files in. I'm wondering if it's possible to change (with babel?) .scss imports to .css imports.

Currently:

```
import './MyStylesFile.scss';
```

Expected:

```
import './MyStylesFile.css';
```

Then reason is, that I don't what user, f.e. to force using sass-loader, when working with webpack.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to do? Do you want your physical file to keep the .scss extension or do you want .css to load the .scss file? Both things are doable, the first is just a matter of modifying the loader while for the second you should be able to do it with the NormalModuleReplacementPlugin

Comment: I don't want to do anything with files. Only I want to do is to transform lines of code, that are currently `import './MyStylesFile.scss';` to `import './MyStylesFile.css';`. I have gulp task that compiles scss files to css, so in my dist dir will be only css files, but in react file there will be still import of `.scss` files

Comment: @JarosławWlazło have you managed to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe [babel-plugin-transform-rename-import](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-rename-import) can help in your case. You could use it like this in your `babel.rc`

```
{
  ...,
  "env": {
    "production": {
      "plugins": [
        ["transform-rename-import",
         { "original": "./MyStylesFile.scss", 
           "replacement": "./MyStylesFile.css"
         }],
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Additionally it supports regex for more complex use cases.
Make sure the env in the tree matches the one you compile in.